# How to detect compiler warnings in gitlab CI

Tags: gcc, gitlab-ci, compiler-warnings

In the steps of setting up CI builds on our gitlab server, I can't seem to find information on how to set up the detection of compiler warnings. Example build output:

```
[100%] Building CXX object somefile.cpp.o
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/XXXXXXX/0/group/project/src/somefile.cpp:14:2: warning: #warning ("This is a warning to test gitlab") [-Wcpp]
 #warning("This is a warning to test gitlab")
 ^
```

However the build result is `success` instead of `warning` or something similar. Ideally the results wuold also be visible on the merge request on the feature (and block the merge if possible).

I can't imagine I'm the only one trying to achieve this, so I am probably looking in the wrong direction. The 'best' solution I found is to somehow manually parse the build output and generate a JUnit report.

How would I go about doing this without allowing the build job to fail, since I would like the job to fail when compiler errors occur.

**Update**

For anyone stumbling across this question later, and in lieu of a best practice, this is how I solved it:

```
stages:
  - build
  - check-warnings

shellinspector:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cmake -Bcmake-build -S.
    - make -C cmake-build > >(tee make.output) 2> >(tee make.error)
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - make.output
      - make.error
    expire_in: 1 week

analyse build:
  stage: check-warnings
  script:
    - "if [[ $(cat make.error | grep warning -i) ]]; then cat make.error; exit 1; fi"
  allow_failure: true
```

This stores the build output errors in `make.error` in the first stage, the next stage then queries that file for warnings and fails that stage with `allow_failure: true` to create the `passed with warning` pipeline status I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the solution to such need (e.g., see the issue "Add new CI state: has-warnings" https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1224) has been to introduce the [allow_failure](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#allow_failure) option so that one job can be the compilation itself, which is *not* allowed to fail (if it does, then the pipeline fails) and another job can be the detection of such warnings which *is* allowed to fail (if one is found then the pipeline will not fail).

Also the possibility of defining [warning regex in the .gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/23816) has been requested but it does not exist yet.

Comment: I was hoping to miss something obvious; it was in my expectation that warning detection was available built-in. The links you found I did too but weren't to my liking ;-) Anyway I did set up my pipeline according to your suggestion.