# Gitlab-CI: conditional allow_failure

Tags: if-statement, gitlab-ci, compiler-warnings

I recently started implementing automatic tests for my code, and I noticed that the CI does not catch the warnings of the compiler - the tests are shown as successful even when there are warnings.
I have initially added a flag for the compiler to turn the warnings into errors and `allow_failure=True`, but the problem is that the compiler stops in the first warning->error and does not go through the entire compilation.
I then used the trick explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680450/how-to-detect-compiler-warnings-in-gitlab-ci) to write the warnings into a file, and then test if the file is not zero:

```
    - make 2> >(tee make.warnings)
    - test ! -s make.warnings
```

After the whole compilation is done, this will give an error if there are warnings written to the file - and using `allow_failure=True`, this works for the cases where I have no errors/warnings, but also when I have warnings. However, if I have real errors, this will also be shown as a warning in CI, and will not stop the pipeline because of the `allow_failure=True`.

I could not find a way to `allow_failure=True` depending on something run in the script (without creating a new stage) or using some condition (i.e., if the file is empty or not). Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since there is no condition per se, check out [GitLab 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#control-job-status-using-exit-codes) (January 2021):

> ### Control job status using exit codes
>
> You can use the `allow_failure` keyword to prevent failed jobs from causing an entire pipeline to fail.
>
> Previously, `allow_failure` only accepted boolean values of `true` or `false` but we’ve made improvements in this release.
>
> **Now you can use the `allow_failure` keyword to look for specific script exit codes**.
>
> This gives you more flexibility and control over your pipelines, preventing failures based on the exit codes.
>
> ```yaml
> test_job_1:
>   script:
>     - echo "Run a script that results in exit code 1. This job fails."
>     - exit 1
>   allow_failure:
>     exit_codes: 137
>
> test_job_2:
>   script:
>     - echo "Run a script that results in exit code 137. This job is allowed to fail."
>     - exit 137
>   allow_failure:
>     exit_codes:
>       - 137
>       - 255
> ```
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#allow_failureexit_codes) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/273157).

If you can use as condition an *exit status* of a script, that would be enough for `allow_failure` to be more specific.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much to pointing me to this new improvement of `allow_failure` - much better than the previous one! :)